# is admin (backend ) cacheable?

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, full-page-cache, varnish

I installed varnish, I'm 100% sure varnish works on the frontend. I see the below info in response header in chrome console.

> X-Magento-Cache-Debug:HIT

I don't see the above info in admin side URL, I don't feel the speed improvement also.

I'm not seeing any confirmation about this so I'm just looking confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the backend is not cached and you don't need it to be cached.
Usually there is not much traffic on the backend and you need there to see things real time. FPC will just cause problems.
Not to mention that there is not much to cache because the M2 backend is based on "empty" knockout js templates that use the data coming from ajax calls to display grids or forms.
And there won't be much of a benefit to cache entity collections results.

Comment: Usually having a separated admin server is also a good idea for this .

Answer (score 1):

No

The backend requires authorization and a strict acl.

Even if you asume, there would be anything worth caching in the backend to begin with (most of the stuff there is not cachable anyway) it would be a security nightmare to implement this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, As of my knowledge, Magento admin is not cache-able.
2. After made any changes through admin, They will immediately allpicable on website
3. Front end is only cache-able. So, no worries.